# Fetch JSON from CLOB in SQL Developer

Tags: sql, json, database, oracle

I have a clob field in table with json data in it. And I want to get one value from that json data and process on it. how to get it?

Example:
Table A has 2 columns: id and accounts, where id is string and account is a clob with json data.

Json data is stored like below:

```
{
    "facebook":"xyz@abc.com",
    "gmail":"qwe@jpg.com",
    "instagram":"pqr@mno.com"
}
```

Now I want to get value of gmail form the clob in the table and it should give it like:

ID      Gmail

A1      qwe@jpg.com

C2      lrt@qrs.com

...

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are on Oracle Database 12.1.0.2 or higher, you can use [JSON_VALUE](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions093.htm#SQLRF56668)

```sql
WITH
    table_a (id, accounts)
    AS
        (SELECT 'A1', EMPTY_CLOB () || '{
    "facebook":"xyz@abc.com",
    "gmail":"qwe@jpg.com",
    "instagram":"pqr@mno.com"
}' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'C2', EMPTY_CLOB () || '{
    "facebook":"abc@abc.com",
    "gmail":"lrt@qrs.com",
    "instagram":"tuv@mno.com"
}' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'B3', EMPTY_CLOB () || '{
    "facebook":"123@abc.com"
}' FROM DUAL)
SELECT id, json_value (accounts, '$.gmail') AS gmail
  FROM table_a;


   ID          GMAIL
_____ ______________
A1    qwe@jpg.com
C2    lrt@qrs.com
B3
```